# Not allowed to load local resource: Why?

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

When a request for main.do comes in, it reads the file in the folder path. We then put the loaded file into the ModelAndView object and pass it to the main.jsp page.

**Controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping("main.do")
public ModelAndView mainPage(HttpSession session)
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    mav.addObject("slideList", aService.readSlideFileList("slide"));
    mav.setViewName("mainPage");

    return mav;
}
```

**Service.java**

```
public List<HashMap<String, Object>> readSlideFileList(String way)
    {
        File dir = new File(path + way + "/");

        if(!dir.isDirectory())
            dir.mkdirs();

        File[] fileList = dir.listFiles();

        //List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        for (File file : fileList)
        {
            HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            if (file.isFile())
            {
                map.put("filePath", file.getName());
                System.out.println("map > " + map);
            }
            list.add(map);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

When I first tried this, I got an error like the title, so I wrote something like this:

```
if (file.isFile())
{
    map.put("filePath", path + way + "/" + file.getName());
    System.out.println("map > " + map);
}
```

As a result, the resulting value of map is:

```
map > C:/rachel/slide/"file name"
```

I tried to display this map manually. (As show below:)

```
<c:forEach items="${slideList}" var="slideName">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="${slideName.filePath}"/>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

The above results are expressed in Google Developer Tools.

```
<img src="C:/rachel/"file path">
```

However, this causes an error such as a title.

So I tried the following.

**Server.xml**

```
<Context docBase="rachelivf" path="/rachelivf" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:rachelivf"/>
 <!-- <Context docBase="C:/rachel" path="/boardFile" reloadable="ture"/> -->
 <Context docBase="C:/rachel" path="/slide" reloadable="true"/>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:resources location="/slide/**" mapping="c:/rachel/**"></mvc:resources>
```

**main.jsp**

```
<c:forEach items="${slideList}" var="slideName">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="/slide/${slideName.filePath}"/>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

(Modify the service logic again)

```
    if (file.isFile())
    {
        map.put("filePath", file.getName());
        System.out.println("map > " + map);
    }
```

As a result, the error has changed.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

In fact, as you've seen from Google developer tools,
The  tag is expressed as:

```
<img src="/slide/2f03c6f8-f5c1-4e6b-bf1c-c70398c118d4.png">
```

How do I display an image? I don t know what I'm doing wrong.

Tell us what you think.

I need help.

Answer (score 1):

I solve that.

The code has been modified as follows.

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:resources location="/slide/**" mapping="c:/rachel/**"></mvc:resources>
```

**server.xml**

```
<Context docBase="C:/rachel" path="/slideImg/" reloadable="true"/>
```

**main.jsp**

```
    <c:forEach items="${slideList}" var="slideName">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/slideImg/slide/${slideName.filePath}"/>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
```

As a result,

[image]

It's very well work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="/slide/2f03c6f8-f5c1-4e6b-bf1c-c70398c118d4.png">
```

Please you try add context with url :

```
/context-path/slide/2f03c6f8-f5c1-4e6b-bf1c-c70398c118d4.png
```

Comment: you mean context-path was c:\rachel ?

Comment: um..? I do not feel it.

Comment: localhost:8080/rachelivf/main.do/slide/2f03c6f8-f5c1-4e6b-bf1c-c70398c118d4.png ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ..

at the top of the JSP file the following

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

and the following at the place where you want.

```
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/img/${slideName.filePath}"></c:url>">
```

Here /resources/img/ is the location where you have kept the files or In your case where you have kept the slides . 
Note that src is taking relative path.

Comment: <c:forEach items="${slideList}" var="slideName">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
     <img src="<c:url value="/slide/${slideName.filePath}"/>"/>
    </div>
   </c:forEach>

Comment: Are you using  Maven or normal project structure ?

Comment: I use Maven in project.

Comment: result was rachelivf/slide/"file name"

Comment: I have given another answer , can you check the structure and you need to keep the images in that way .. then the above code will work

Comment: I will check. currently I m eat lunch. wait please.

Comment: okay great. we should be cool and understand the problem in different ways. one of the way gives solution to our problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the structure ..
[image]

Comment: I don t understand what s you mean.

Comment: Can you post the structure of your project , the way I have given to as Image .

Comment: I store the image externally and only import images stored outside. Is it related to the image you attached?